# Adobe premiere - dedicated method for split frame video?

Tags: premiere

I'm after a video that has a short clip of me tying two different shoes. Here is a still frame with the desired effect:

[image]

### Question

Does premiere have anything built-in to achieve this kind of effect? As it stands, I only seem to be able to add the clips in one at a time, but I don't see any functionality for the split-frame effect I desire. If there is nothing built-in, do I have other options?

Answer (score 2):

You should position two tracks differently, one to the left and one to the right. Those tracks need also croppings to have the interesting part visible. See for ex. this tutorial video: [Adobe Premiere Pro Tutorial: How to create Split Screen Side by Side Video Effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h553RFrWL2w).

There's more of them, search for “Premiere split screen”.

Comment: You can also mask the opacity to make the split any shape you want.  Could be wavy or zigzag, eg.